# Include bootstrap 3 classes in Magento2

Tags: magento2, css

How to include bootstrap 3 classes in Magento2.

till know i was using

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>.
```

But i need to remove some css from bootstrap as it is over lapping my current css.

Comment: have tried yet..?

Comment: Yes. till know i was using  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>.

Comment: If you want to remove some bootstrap you will need to replace bootstrapcdn version with a local copy.

Comment: Yes. but i don't know where to place it (.css & .js of bootstrap) in local copy of magento2. or how to implement it in custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove some bootstrap you will need to replace bootstrapcdn version with a local copy. Download bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Update http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" to the path of your theme and point to a local version of bootstrap css, you can then remove the styles which are causing you issues.

Comment: Thanks Man. I added bootstrap css in a local folder of magento2 in my custom module and now i am able to make changes. (for ref. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html)

Comment: No worries if you plan on customizing a framework also opt for a using a local copy as appose to cdn